# how to use a single application to create multiple tabs with different contents?

Tags: tabs, facebook-page

how to use  a single application to create multiple tabs with different content, like pagemode.com,wix.com. This is possible because they are using single app for creating multiple tabs on multiple pages with different content.Any help?

Answer (score 0):

We can create multiple tabs with different content for a single application id, this is possible by parsing the signed request and get the page id and then redirect to a URL which we want display in the Iframe.